# Can we install VC++ 2015 Redistributable Package in custom location, where as non-administrator has rights to access?

Tags: visual-c++, clickonce, visual-studio-2015, redistributable, regfreecom

We have VC++ projects in VS 2008 and Wpf Projects in 2010. We want to migrate both of them to Visual Studio 2015.

The biggest problem we face, while a new user needed to install our software is, he need to install the pre-requisite of installing VC++ Redistributable Package, which requires Administrator rights. Then he need to install our application via clickonce server.

We want to ease this part - installing VC++ Redistributable Package.

Is the new 2015 VC++ Redistributable can be installed in my application path, without requiring administrator rights? I could not the spot the link to download VS 2015 VC++ R P link - please provide.

I got the suggestion of using /MT (linking statically) from below link, but we want the application to be statble (as we also dispatch patches), we don't want a library conflict.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8d4ca59-c295-43bf-b34e-518fe2f7977c/vc-2015-redistributable-package?forum=vclanguage#667db896-f517-4fa5-b5b7-b5b0c3d12d52

Please, help.

Comment: The simple way seems to go for Local Deployment, which meets pretty much my requirment. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235316.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Currently you can't redistribute anything VS2015 related, as it's not yet released and the license doesn't allow for it yet.

Answer (score 2):

I believe no, you can't do that.
Read this article at VC++ team blog: [Introducing the Universal CRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx), where James McNellis said:

> App-local deployment of the Universal CRT is not supported.

Comment: They did respond in the comments that they are re-evaluating it in light of the negative feedback they received there, but no word if any decision was reached yet. So right now, that's what we have to assume.

Comment: And now...there is an update from 11Sep 2015 in that post that says it is supported.